# Separate input to input + button

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this, which is buggy on production (keeps blocking at 1) :

```php
<input
  type="number"
  size="2"
  min="0"
  max="10"
  name="res_ao"
  id="res_ao"
  value="<?= $AO ? $AO : 0 ?>"
  onclick="gestionRecensementAccueil('enr_rec_<?= $res_num; ?>','ao',<?= $AO_num ?>,this.value);
">
```

I want to separate it into an input and a button like this :

```php
<input
  type="number"
  size="2"
  min="0"
  max="10"
  name="res_ao"
  id="res_ao"
  value="<?= $AO ? $AO : 0 ?>
">
<button onclick="gestionRecensementAccueil('enr_rec_<?= $res_num; ?>','ao',<?= $AO_num ?>,res_ao);">
    Button
</button>
```

But that doesn't work, I can't get the value of the input back... any help is welcome.

EDIT :

Some asked the function here it is :

```
function gestionRecensementAccueil(form, appareil, pro_num, val) {
var a = document.getElementById(form);

//console.log(a);

var identifiant = a.identifiant.value;
var res_num = a.res_num.value;


var data = 'res_num=' + res_num + '&identifiant=' + identifiant + '&appareil=' + appareil + '&valeur=' + val + '&pro_num=' + pro_num;

var xhr_object = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // Firefox
    xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
else if (window.ActiveXObject) // Internet Explorer
    xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
else { // XMLHttpRequest non supporté par le navigateur
    alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas les objets XMLHTTPRequest...");
    return;
}
xhr_object.open("GET", 'recensement_accueil_req.php?' + data, true);
xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr_object.readyState === 4) {
                    console.log(xhr_object.responseText)
        eval(xhr_object.responseText);
    }
};
xhr_object.send(null);
```

}

Comment: As we don't know what your function is supposed to do, it's hard to debug your code.

Comment: nothing fancy, the point here is how to get the value from the input to the button

Comment: I edited my post and added the Ajax if you are curious anyway

Comment: what is res_num?

Comment: resident number - just a line in SQL

Comment: i am not asking that, show mi a piece of code in your function where you are selecting value of that input

Comment: `foreach ($residents as $resident) {
 $identifiant = '';
 $action     = '';

 $res_num    = $resident["res_num"];
`

Comment: wait, we do not get eachother, obviously. i understand that your problem is inability to get value from input element, am i right?

Comment: yeah, I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 0):

well you are not getting that element anywhere in your function, as much as I can see.
First of all, i am not sure that your form is structured well at all, so in your function, I will guess that, one of this two variables should be this input:

```
var a = document.getElementById(form);

//console.log(a);

var identifiant = a.identifiant.value;
var res_num = a.res_num.value;
```

so, in case that form is valid there is option(i will consider that res_num is correct field) :

```
var a = document.getElementById(form);

//console.log(a);

var identifiant = a.identifiant.value;
var res_num = a['res_ao'].value;
```

or simply

```
var res_num = document.getElementById('res_ao').value;
```